# What's the regex for literals intermixed with variables containing literals?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a custom C# app (.NET 4.7.1) that needs to evaluate various and sundry text strings. As one of many cases, I have the following string in the midst of other text:

```
OR S:D00Q0600 ) OR
```

I need to find these precise situations (each string segment will be surrounded by a single space, or be at the beginning or end of a line) in which there is an `OR` followed by a string containing a `:`, followed by a `)`, followed by another `OR`. The `ORs` are literal and the `:` within the string is literal, and the `)` is literal -- but the `D00Q0600` is variable and will be different every time.

And when that precise situation occurs I need to replace the string with:

```
OR S:D00Q0600 OR
```

(Simply remove the `)` - from that little snippet only - not the whole string)

So to break it down a little cleaner:

1. Find an `OR` (always uppercase)
2. ...followed by a space followed by a string with a `:`
3. ...followed by a space followed by a `)`
4. ...followed by a space followed by an `OR`
5. When found, remove the `)` in that position
6. Do not remove any other `)`s which will often exist in the entire string
7. In many cases, the `)` is correct and must remain; only in the case described above should it be removed.

**S:D00Q0600 can be of variable length. It could also be (for example) S:D00Q or S:D00Q0600XYZ, etc.**

How can I construct the type of C# regex that would solve this?

Comment: What regexes have you tried and how did they fail? Please show us a set of input data items that should match and also a set of items that shouldn't match. Showing us relevant code and data makes it much easier for us to provide you with a relevant answer.

Comment: I gave explicit examples of the data string that should match, but I apologize I don't even know where to start with experimental regexes.

Comment: Is the length and format of this variable S:D00Q0600 same or variable? Like can it be S:D00Q only?

Comment: Sorry, the length is variable. It always contains a colon and will always be surrounded by boundaries such as space or BOL/EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and do replace with what matches with group 1 and group 2. This ensures that only when this regex matches, the replace occurs.

```
(OR [A-Z]:[A-Z0-9]+ )\) (OR)
```

Check here,

https://regex101.com/r/0EZiu6/1/

Edit 1:

Modified your c# code and now this works.

```
string pattern = @"(OR [A-Z]:[A-Z0-9]+ )\) (OR)";
string substitution = @"$1$2";
string input = @"OR S:D00Q0600 ) OR ok sir how )r u OR S:D11Q06 ) OR i ()am fine OR D:D67Q06S0A23DR ) OR";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
Console.WriteLine("Before Replace: " + input);
Console.WriteLine("After Replace: " + result);
```

I have just replaced \1 \2 with $1 $2 and added print statement in last to print the result before and after replace.

Following is the output of this program which is exactly as you desired.

```
Before Replace: OR S:D00Q0600 ) OR ok sir how )r u OR S:D11Q06 ) OR i ()am fine OR D:D67Q06S0A23DR ) OR
After Replace: OR S:D00Q0600 OR ok sir how )r u OR S:D11Q06 OR i ()am fine OR D:D67Q06S0A23DR OR
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising...I'm looking at the c# code here: https://regex101.com/r/0EZiu6/1/codegen?language=csharp - but I'm puzzled because the substituion of `\1\2` injects that literal string into my string. That's not right. Is `\1\2` some kind of metaphor that I'm supposed to figure out?

Comment: When you make groups in a regex, then what matched in the group can be captured using \1 \2 for group1 and group2 respectively. I've seen your c# code and looks like \1\2 doesn't work there instead you need to write $1 and $2. I am editing my answer to add a working code for c#. Please use that and let me know if that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the single example of

```
OR S:D00Q0600 ) OR
```

... this regex works:

```
(\bOR S:........ )\)( OR\b)
```

with the replacing groups being `$1` and `$2`.

The regex assumes that the length of the middle string will always be seven characters. If you have more/different input data, please update your question with examples where this regex fails.

#### Explanation

```
(\bOR S:........ )\)( OR\b)
```

`\b` assert position at a word boundary (transition from non-word to word, or from word to non-word)

`OR S:` matches the characters literally (case sensitive)

`.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

matches the character  literally (case sensitive)

`\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/58Ve1s/1)